# best way to set multiple html attribute without making a usercontrol or using literal control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Trying to find the best way to dynamically add a direction attribute to each of these html elements. I know how to obtain the direction with

```
var dir = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft ? "rtl" : "ltr";
```

but I need to find a graceful way to dynamically add it to the following html

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="ie6" lang="en"><![endif]-->;
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="ie7" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="ie8" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
```

If I put this into a User Control and assign each html element an id, then set each control's direction attribute, I get runtime errors for not having a closing html tag in the user control.

Is there any simple way for me to set the `dir` attribute for each of these html elements without doing it through a user control? I'm not even able to place a `<asp:Literal>` control within each html tag, and it is beginning to frustrate me. Thanks

edit: the end result should be

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="ie6" lang="en" dir="ltr"><![endif]-->;
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="ie7" lang="en" dir="ltr"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="ie8" lang="en" dir="ltr"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html lang="en" dir="ltr"><!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `<asp:Literal>` control to output the entire result.  You can generate the entire excerpt in code-behind and then feed it to the literal control.

Or, you could create a public function:

```
public string Direction() {
    return (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft) ? "rtl" : "ltr";
}
```

And call it from within your aspx page:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="ie6" lang="en" <%=Direction()%>><![endif]-->;
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="ie7" lang="en" <%=Direction()%>><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="ie8" lang="en" <%=Direction()%>><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html lang="en" <%=Direction()%>><!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Why use a literal when you can work with the attributes in the html tag?

Comment: totally forgot that I could just use <%= string %>. FiveTools, having an html tag left open in the user control generates a runtime error for me (I described this in my question)

Answer (score 1):

Put a runat=server in the tag:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" id="html_tag" runat="server">
```

then add any of the conditional attributes you need in your code behind, such as:

```
html_tag.Attributes.Add("dir", "ltr");
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be set using [CSS](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-bidi-css-markup) as well, and if you're setting multiple items, it may be to your advantage to do it this way. Have your items use an additional class, like:

Somewhere else on the page (preferable above), put a Literal on the page and make it's text emit an inline style:

```
Literal.Text = String.Concat("<style> .useLTR {", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft ? "direction: rtl;" : String.Empty, "} </style>");
```